# What is the easiest way to gain access to the spell Silence (or similar effect)?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I'm currently playing a Fighter 2 / Rogue 1 (working toward Fighter X Battlemaster / Rogue 3 Assassin). What is the easiest way of gaining access to the spell silence? Specifically, I want it for the ability to shut down enemy spellcasters, so if there's a similar effect that can turn off spells with Verbal components, I'd consider that.

I've considered:

- Spell Scrolls - I think I'd need to pick up at least one rank of spellcaster MC to use
- Multiclass Monk - Way of Shadow gives access to Silence (and Darkvision and Pass Without Trace)
- Multiclass to Cleric (or other caster) - And pick it up the normal way

Are there other, more accessible options? MC is fine for long term, but I won't be able to pick up another class for quite a few levels. Are there magic items that would let a non-caster use silence?

Comment: What do you mean by more accessible? More immediate, less costly?

Comment: Do you want to cast silence in combat or is a ritual-cast fine?

Comment: @DavidCoffron Yes. Easier to access. i.e. not requiring another three levels of multi-classing. If I could buy a "potion of silence", I would do that.

Combat speed would be ideal... but ritual cast might work, I suppose.

Comment: @T.J.L. Honestly, that's an interesting thought. I really was angling on a mega-assassinate build... I guess it's something to consider when I hit rogue 3. Problem is, I've already dumped INT.

Comment: I don't see Silence on the Wizard spell list.  I only see it on Bard, Cleric, and Ranger, so Arcane Trickster still couldn't learn Silence by RAW.  This surprised me when I looked it up.

Comment: @NickBrown you are correct. I just assumed. Will edit OP

Comment: @NickBrown Color me flabbergasted... I assumed it was as well.

Comment: (Just out of curiosity, has the DM already approved this plan? My table's gentlemen's agreement sees *silence* and similar effects go unused because using them means *every caster in the setting* (both PCs and NPCs) must devote resources to being able to deal with those effects, and we found that no fun.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan I haven't brought it up yet, but noted. It's just something I'm starting to think about now, and yes, I always intended to bring the DM in on the plan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Magic Items

The only non-legendary (since you are low level) magic item in the Dungeon Master's Guide that can cast *silence* is the Ring of Spell Storing if you have an ally that can cast it for use later (up to two instances can be stored).

You could talk to your GM about homebrewing a Wand of Silence based on the Wand of Web item which would only require you to get the ability to cast at least one spell to use:

> **Wand of Web**
>
> *Wand, rare (Requires attunement by a spellcaster)*
>
> This wand has 7 charges. While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 of its charges to cast the *web* spell (save DC 15) from it.
>
> The wand regains 1d6 + 1 expended Charges daily at dawn. If you expend the wand's last charge, roll a d20. On a 1, the wand crumbles into ashes and is destroyed.

### Ritual Caster feat

If you have time to setup, this feat gives you access *silence* if you find either a spellbook or scroll with *silence* on it (but only as a ritual).

> If you come across a spell in written form, such as a magical spell scroll or a wizard’s spellbook, you might be able to add it to your ritual book. The spell must be on the spell list for the class you chose, the spell’s level can be no higher than half your level (rounded up), and it must have the ritual tag

Unfortunately, this does require Intelligence or Wisdom of 13 or higher to function so it might not be feasible for your character (at least not with some sub-optimal ASIs or a Headband of Intellect)

Comment: Excellent options. Hadn't considered ring of spell storing, but that's the kind of obscure idea I had been hoping to hear.

Comment: Silence as a ritual would technically work, but can't be considered part of a useful build.  10 minutes to cast it into a fixed point and it lasts for 10 minutes (concentration required).  It would be great for the rare ambush if you could somehow avoid detection while preparing the ritual.  ***Ring of Spell Storing*** however is a great idea.  I would swap the order of your answer.

Comment: @NickBrown Good thought; I added ritual caster because of a comment from the OP that said it would be fine, but he preferred a combat option.

Answer (score 3):

There are no magic items in the DMG which cast Silence.  Your DM might let you commission a Wand of Silence, but that would be up to your DM.  And as David pointed out, if you have a Ring of Spell Storing and a friendly caster that doesn't mind filling it with Silence you can go that route.

Gaining the 2nd-level Silence spell would require investing 3 levels of multiclassing into Bard, Cleric, Ranger, Land(Desert) Druid, or Undying Warlock.  3 levels of Way of Shadow Monk could also give you Shadow Arts which lets you cast it with 2 ki points.

You might consider the Mage Slayer feat instead.  You won't be able to cast Silence, but you will be quite formidable against adjacent spell casters.  This will only cost you a feat rather than the extra multiclassing.

Comment: Other multiclasses include Land Druid (Desert) and Undying Warlock

Comment: Mage Slayer feat is already on my "to buy" list, but thanks for mentioning. I think my character is headed down an "I hate magic" path, and I'm just trying to figure out what tools he can have at his dispoal.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Undying warlock is VERY cool (and on theme for a master assassin). Definitely something to consider in the long term.